# Passing filename to a subprocess from within Python

Tags: python, subprocess, filenames

I'm having problems calling an external command from within a python routine. I've written code before that calls simple commands but this one is a bit trickier and I'm just floundering around and getting nowhere.

The command is one of the GMT (Generic Mapping Tools) commands - "gmtselect" which takes a file of latitude/longitude coordinates and sees which ones are within a polygon defined by a series of lat/long points in a separate file.

If we call these two file "points.txt" and "polygon.txt" then from the command line the call would be:

```
gmtselect <polygon.txt -Fpolygon.txt
```

I've tried various ways but cannot see how to do this using subprocess.Popen

Any informed suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your command-line example?

Comment: If an answer works for you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    subprocess.run(['gmtselect', '-Fother.txt'], stdin=f)
```

Comment: That works @askaroni. I had a logic error in the example I was using so no output. Simplified it and all OK. Thnaks